# Overriding method with generics parameter

Tags: java, generics, overriding

We have a method in class that takes generic parameter

```
public class XYZ {
     public <T extends Animal> someMethod(T animal){}
}
```

I want to override this method in the subclass with specific type, but don't know how. How to fix this?

```
public class ABC extends XYZ{
  @Override
  public Cat someMethod(Cat animal){}  // error
}
```

Comment: `public <T extends Animal> someMethod(T animal){}` is pretty much equivalent to `public someMethod(Animal animal){}`

Comment: That makes sense. The code that calls this method, I was assigning to generic type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution would be to make your `XYZ` class generic:

```
public class XYZ<T extends Animal> {

    public void someMethod(T animal) {
    }
}
```

And declare your `ABC` class to be specific to cats:

```
public class ABC extends XYZ<Cat> {
}
```

Now you can write:

```
ABC cats = new ABC();
cats.someMethod(new Cat()); //ok
cats.someMethod(new Dog()); //does not compile
```